# Bootstrap Tab Pagination

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, pagination

I have been searching for a bootstrap tab pagination snippet over the web and can't find one anywhere, so I thought i'd put something together using JQuery and share it with you lovely people!

Hope this helps someone

Comment: I'll delete it then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer.

```
//.pager is the pagination container
$('.pager').find('.previous, .next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //.nav-tabs is the tabs container
    var tabs = $('.nav-tabs');
    var currentTab = $(tabs).find('.active');
    var previousTab = $(currentTab).prev();
    var nextTab = $(currentTab).next();
    //find if the event's class is next or previous
    if ( $(this).is('.previous') ) {
        $(previousTab).find('a').click();
    }
    if ( $(this).is('.next') ) {
        $(nextTab).find('a').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice. Are you able to provide a demonstration? Here's a Bootstrap base fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bz88LrLn/

Comment: Oh Yes, ill have something up in a sec :-)